# How to set up Dolphin as default file manager?

Tags: dolphin

I've recently came back to Ubuntu from Kubuntu, but I really like Dolphin. Is there any way how to set it up as default file manager?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Steps:

1. Open a terminal, e.g. using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Install `exo-utils` by running the following command in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install exo-utils
   ```
3. Run the following command in the terminal:

   ```
   exo-preferred-applications
   ```
4. In the window that opens, click on *Utilities*
5. On the *File Manager* section, click the drop-down menu arrow + Other...
6. Find `/usr/share/applications` directory
7. Adjust to show all files and select `dolphin.desktop` (wherever you find it)
8. Click *close*

Comment: I couldnt get this to work in Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Didn't work for me  either on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Is this still valid for 16.04?  Didnt seem to work for me.

Comment: Not working: exo-preferred-applications 
/usr/bin/exo-preferred-applications: 11: exec: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/exo-1/exo-helper-1: not found

Comment: @tribbloid -- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=892010 -- At step 2, use `sudo apt install libexo-1-0 exo-utils`

Comment: No way to get this to work on Ubuntu 18.04 either.

Comment: This did not work for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 49):

To view the current default for opening directories:

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

To set Dolphin as default:

```
xdg-mime default org.kde.dolphin.desktop inode/directory
```

To set Thunar as default:

```
xdg-mime default thunar.desktop inode/directory
```

Run either on the terminal as regular user. If you want to set the default to another file manager, install the file manager, and find the correct `.desktop` file by searching in `/usr/applications/` on the command-line.

---

Related files:

- `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` system-wide defaults
- `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`
- `$HOME/.config/mimeapps.list` where `xdg-mime` saves configuration

Sources:

- http://www.fandigital.com/2013/01/set-nemo-default-file-manager-ubuntu.html
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_Applications
- http://packages.debian.org/sid/ia64/dolphin/filelist

Comment: this actually works if you are using synapse. The solution should be a combination of all the above answers.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Also, if you want to set PCManFM, the file name is all lowercase, `pcmanfm.desktop`.

Comment: Is this still valid for 16.04?  Didnt seem to work for me.

Comment: This works for me with Ubuntu 16.04 and seems to be the easier solution.

Comment: Perfect. It is a better solution than the selected as answer because you dont have to install any other program

Comment: still xdg-open uses the default file manager of Ubuntu to open a directory for me (instead of using Dolphin)

Answer (score 7):

Adding to Rucent88 answer:

For me the dolphin desktop file was stored in `/usr/share/applications/org.kde.dolphin.desktop`. So

```
xdg-mime default org.kde.dolphin.desktop inode/directory
```

did the trick.

Keep in mind to have a look where the desktop link is located. Have a look at the [file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/dolphin/filelist) of your installed file manager to see how the desktop link is called if you can't find it.

Comment: If this is an addition, perhaps you should suggest an edit to it.

Answer (score 3):

also it works only with:

```
xdg-mime default dolphin.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

From:
http://www.fandigital.com/2013/01/set-nemo-default-file-manager-ubuntu.html

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Comment: Hi Flimm the link is down

Answer (score 1):

In My, **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS** below solution worked. Not sure, is there are any consequences for this approach.

In file `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` modified entry `inode/directory=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` to `inode/directory=org.kde.dolphin.desktop`

Answer (score 0):

As exo-preffered-applicatiosn from exo-utils have been depreciated and moved to xfce4-settings.
Use the following steps:

1. Open the terminal `Ctrl+Alt+T`.
2. Install xcfe4-settings `sudo apt install xfce4-settings`
3. Type `xfce4-mime-settings`in terminal.
4. A window will appear, click on Utilities in it.
5. Go to File Manager section and click on others
6. Open /usr/share/applications directory and set from exectuable files to all files.
7. Select for org.kde.dolphin.desktop and open it.
8. Close