# getting error when trying to use dolphin instead of Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, dolphin

I am getting the following error while trying to use dolphin instead of Nautilus.

```
"Failed to execute child process "/usr/share/applications/kde4/dolphin.desktop" (Permission denied)"
```

I used the soultion of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/234532/75400) to get Dolphin as the default file manager. Please guide me what next to do.

PS : tried to change permissions as well and it did not work.

Using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 5):

Although this is an old question, the same happened to me recently.

The solution I found:

On command line:
$exo-preferred-applications -c

In Preferred Applications dialog that opens:
Utilities tab --> File Manager
Change:
/usr/share/applications/kde4/dolphin.desktop"%s"
to just:
dolphin "%s"

An alternative solution may be to completely remove the exo-utils package

(Note: I am running KDE, but the Default Applications section in KDE System Settings had no effect (was already set to Dolphin). The application exo-preferred-applications appears to be from the xfce desktop environment.)