# Can I install Nautilus 3.4(Ubuntu 12.10) into UbuntuStudio 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, thunar

I now understand Thunar is a quick, lightweight menu system. However, I really liked the List/tree view, and the extra pane view in Ubuntu 12.10.

Should I instead install Nautilus 3.6 (or whatever is the most current), and then somehow "activate" these two features?

I tried adding Nautilus from the software Center, I somehow made a mess, and had to reinstall UbuntuStudio 14.04.

I have thought of simply intalling (plain, Unity) Ubuntu, only 14.04 Nautilus lacks the same features. I also like the integrated software install of UbuntuStudio.

Actually, If I could just add these 2 features in Thunar, I would prefer this.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you may install any file manager you want, but it won't be default file manager. Personally, I have Dolphin installed, but Nautilus is still default and whenever I say to firefox to open a downloaded file in folder, it opens with Nautilus.

If you want to change default file manager you can refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/234532/295286) post, just make sure to adjust accordingly ( since this post is for making Dolphin a default file manager )