# Help, I broke my desktop. How do I reset it?

Tags: 14.04, unity

My desktop appears to be broken. I can no longer see any shortcuts I placed on my desktop. When holding down the mouse and then moving the mouse I also no longer see any selection area. The desktop background is stuck at whatever it was at the login screen (trying to change the background in the settings menu has no effect).

Luckily the side bar with program links still works. All GUI programs still work so it seems to be isolated to the desktop.

Is there any way to reset the desktop? I'm not really sure what I did to cause this. A recent change I did make was trying to change my default file browser from Nautilus to Krusader using the top answer in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84929/how-to-set-up-dolphin-as-default-file-manager) post. Please note the poster of this question was asking for Dolphin not Krusader. Maybe this caused the error. I can't think of anything else that might have caused this.

I already tried the suggestions on [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html) website but they did not work.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bits with the latest updates.

Comment: My apologies, but I'm confused. You mention changing the file manager from Nautilus to Krusader but the post you linked is about Dolphin. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/462914/how-to-reinstall-unity-desktop-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @ElderGeek I figured the answer given would be same for any other file browser even though the poster was asking for Dolphin. The answer seemed quite generic so I gave it a try. The reason I posted the link was to let other people know the exact steps I followed.

Comment: The comment was in regard to the question, not the answer. My apologies if that led to confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. After some more searching around I discovered Nautilus was removed from my system. I discovered this because I could not launch Nautilus from a terminal window (command not found).

After installing Nautilus using

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

and doing a reboot everything worked again.

I have no idea how I managed to get Nautilus removed from my system.